# Populate autoComplete from database

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I have been playing around with autoComplete, and while I see several general examples, I have found nothing explaining how to connect to and retrieve the auto complete items from a database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request to an API and add the list of the autoComplete while the page load or while the user is typing.

This is a thing you can view on [w3schools: How to create a Autocomplete on an Input Field](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).